Filling byte array from Int16 values
I'm trying to use BitConverter.GetBytes to transfer 16 bit values into a byte array using VB.net. The simple readBuffer(z) = BitConverter.GetBytes(p) is rejected by vb.net. What is going wrong?
Thanks for any advice!
readBuffer(z) = BitConverter.GetBytes(p)

fails to compile
readBuffer() is a Byte array and p is a Int16 variable.

GetBytes method returns an array that needs to be copied to a specific position in your array:
BitConverter.GetBytes(p).CopyTo(readBuffer, z)


Many thanks Konstantin - problem solved!
